# Showing that $k(x,x') = (x^Tx' -1)^2 $ is not a valid kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, positive-definite, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I would like to show that $k(x,x') = (x^Tx' -1)^2 $ is not a valid kernel.

Is it possible to show the non-positive semi definiteness by considering a special subspace of the feature space?

In other words;

Can I say that for a particular feature space I only consider x,y such that $<\phi(x), \phi(y)> > 1$ when $x \neq y $ and $1$ otherwise (i.e. have $1$ on the diagonal)?

Then for a $2\times2$ matrix, or the second principal minor of any larger symmetric matrix I would have a negative determinant and thus some negative eigenvalues somewhere.

Feels like cheating, apologies if this is really silly, I can't poke a hole in the reasoning yet.
Thanks for explaining why it can work or why it is wrong.

Comment: You can say whatever you want about $k$ as long as it is actually true. Furthermore, you can pick any points $x$, $x'$ to make your argument. But better make sure points with the properties you need do indeed exist, e.g. by stating their values explicitely.

Comment: @gg thanks! I am trying to wrap my head around your comment but I think I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think a kernel function should meet this condition: k(x,z)=∅(x).∅(z)
(x,z)=[(∑x_i.z_i-1)(∑x_j.z_j-1)= ∑∑x_i.z_i.x_j.z_j-2∑x_i.z_i +1]
Because of having minus in:-2∑x_i.z_i  ,we cannot find a feature map ∅
have you solved this problem?

Comment: See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/888233) for formatting help.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1694746)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x = (0,1)^T$ and $y=(1,0)^T$, then the kernel matrix is
$$K = \begin{pmatrix}k(x,x)&k(x,y)\\k(y,x)&k(y,y)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},$$ which is not positive semi-definite, because its determinant is $-1$, or let $c = (1,-1)^T$, we have
$$c^TKc = -2<0.$$ Therefore $k(x,y)$ is not a valid kernel!